# How to pass javascript variable(ie legend on clcik in HC) value in sql data base table in high chart?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

When ever legend is click , what I want is to store the value of that click legend in the database table using php sql insert.

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
events: {                                          
legendItemClick: function (e) {
legname.push(this.name);
for (i=1; i<5; i++){
a[i] = legname[i-1]; 
var b = a[i]; 
<?php 
$legend_sql = "INSERT INTO device_table(device_key) VALUES('".b."')";
// echo  $legend_sql;
//die;
$conn->query($legend_sql);
?>
}
}
},
showInLegend: true
}
},
```

this is the chart [image]

Comment: Use ajax for this purpose

Comment: you mean to pass it in url and create another page and use sql insert there?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way

Comment: tnx alot I tried this and Now i am storing the data in table.. great half of my work is done and few things are left and then I am done .. thnx again